# How to resolve horzcat error in matlab?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I did some processing on a 2-D binary matrix using a cell array to store information based upon equal values of elements. I have `15` cells, two of which are as follows:

```
similarity{1} = [2 5 8 10 12 13 18 19 20 21 22 23];
similarity{2} = [2 5 8  13 18 19 20 21 22 23];
```

... until `similarity{n}` values in `similarity{1,..n}=n`.

When I run the following code

```
similarity = cellfun(@unique, similarity, 'UniformOutput', false);
numsInCell = unique([similarity{:}]);                  % numbers in cell, sorted

for n = numsInCell % loop over numbers in cell
    lSetIs1 = cellfun(@numel,similarity) == 1;         % length of set is 1
     nInSet = cellfun(@(set) any(set==n), similarity); % set contains n
     nIsUnique = sum(nInSet(:))==1;                    % n occurs once
     condition = ~nIsUnique & ~any(nInSet(:) & lSetIs1(:));

     % if false for all sets...
     if condition
         similarity = cellfun(@(set) set(set~=n), similarity, 'UniformOutput',false); 
     end
end
```

I get following error

> Error using horzcat 
>  
>   Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

and

> Error in @(set)any(set==n)

Can anyone help me identify where I made a mistake?

Comment: No error here with that code. Please post a reproducible example

Comment: @LuisMendo i've updated my question and provided code, i hope you understand the error now, this `similarity` result is based upon 2D matrix

Comment: INDENT YOUR CODE! CNTRL+A, CNTRL+I In Matlab

Comment: Turn on `dbstop if error` and rerun your code.  Then inspect the size of all the variables involved in the error after the debugger.  Some variable isn't the size you expect it to be, and it's easiest to have MATLAB tell you.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible if you don't provide the full inputs that cause the issue so that we can run it and demonstrate the error for ourselves.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, right you are, but please don't shout. :-)

Comment: I recommend you don't use `set` as the anonymous function varlable.  `set` is used in so many other toolboxes that it's just bad practice to shadow that function with a variable.  BTW, I can't reproduce your error.  I used those two cell array inputs and placed them into a cell array called `similarity`.  I can't produce your error.

Comment: @A.Donda Haha sorry, I get a bit nervous with unindented code! :P

Comment: sorry guys my bad, this was a bad question, will re formulate it in a proper way.